# Bootstrap navbar logo overlay

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, navbar

I have a navbar in bootstrap that has the links and a logo in the center. The navbar stretches to fit the logo image, I'd rather have the logo overlap the navbar. Here is my code, I actually used a base someone already made yet it still doesn't work.

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark">
    <div class="navbar-collapse collapse w-100 dual-collapse2 order-1 order-md-0">
        <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto text-center">
            <li class="nav-item active">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="mx-auto my-2 order-0 order-md-1 position-relative">
        <a class="mx-auto" href="#">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/120/ccff00" class="rounded-circle" height="120" width="120">
        </a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".dual-collapse2">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
    </div>
    <div class="navbar-collapse collapse w-100 dual-collapse2 order-2 order-md-2">
        <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto text-center">
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
```

CSS

```
@media (min-width: 992px) {
    .navbar {
        height:50px;
    }
}
```

Comment: What you mean by "the logo overlap the navbar"?

Comment: Actually the logo "overlap" the nav

Comment: https://www.codeply.com/go/0xSGj0EsAu I think this is a good example of what I was trying to do. Notice how the nav doesn't stretch to fit the logo in the center.